The error can't connect postgres after create port 5432 on docker compose file to connect airflow
I config this docker-compose file to connect airflow, i added the 5432 port and it's running on docker desktop
Port 5432 running on docker desktop
But I can't connect postgres desktop and when I go to Services of Window to run postgres, i receive the error
Error when running postgres on service
and when i run the DAG on airflow, it has error
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "host.docker.internal" (192.168.65.254), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" [2024-05-12, 03:12:24 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1149} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=spotify_data_pipeline, task_id=process_and_clean_data_task, execution_date=20240512T031104, start_date=20240512T031223, end_date=20240512T031224 [2024-05-12, 03:12:24 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 883 for task process_and_clean_data_task (connection to server at "host.docker.internal" (192.168.65.254), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
It's seem like having the ports conflict, when i stop the port on docker desktop, i can run postgres on service, but i can't do it when it's turning on docker desktop
I would appreciate with your helps

Pick a different port for one of them.  Or just use one server for all your needs.  Or don't map the port at all, and use the docker network to connect to the docker's db server.
